# Reverse Kanji letters in the console

Tags: terminal, c, unicode

For an application I am develloping right now, (a shogi software), for text mode, i need to make upside down the graphics of the pieces , because the opponent's pieces are reversed. However, Unicode does not provide upside down kanji characters. I am searching to reverse the kanjis in a style similar to this diagram of this wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi#Player_rank_and_handicaps
where they use CSS to do it. I can use filter programs or kernel API (ioctl). Thanks in advance for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the terminal emulators I've heard of supports upside down text, and there's nothing analogous to CSS there.

Technically, one could come up with a certain escape sequence (probably along the lines of the bold, italic, underlined etc. ANSI sequences). Ideally at least a few popular terminal emulators (let's say at least xterm, vte and iterm2) would then implement this feature identically.

I don't see a reasonable chance for this to happen, given that probably your app would be the only app using this feature.

You might want to take a look at various ways that allow to draw pictures inside terminal emulators. The possibilities include Regis and Sixel (I've heard about these but don't know them – don't know if they are good enough for you), or custom solutions offered by some terminal emulators e.g. Terminology or Kitty (I'm not familiar with those solutions either). With such a solution, though, your app will probably be limited to run under a particular terminal emulator. Plus, you'd have to draw the kanjis yourself.

I'd conclude that terminal emulators cannot do what you're looking for, and as such, if you really need upside down glyphs, choosing text mode is a wrong choice. You should go for a graphical app written in a graphical toolkit (e.g. GTK+ or Qt) where rotating text is a piece of cake.

Update:

ECMA-48 defines the `SCO - SELECT CHARACTER ORIENTATION` escape sequences: `\e[0 e` should select the default orientation, `\e[1 e` should rotate subsequent glyphs counter-clockwise by 45°, and so on up to `\e[7 e`. I don't think this was ever implemented anywhere. Also no clue how the glyphs should be stretched and cropped for orientations other than the default and upside down. Anyway, if a terminal emulator ever implements upside down text, it might be reasonable to go with this escape sequence (even if only 0 and 4 are accepted as numeric argument).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. My app runs in graphical and in text mode, so it doesn't hurt my project too much. Distinctive colors seems enough to discern the pieces. and the lambda user is probably gonna use GUI mode 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

John Zaitseff has written some [python utilities](http://www.zap.org.au/software/fonts/console-fonts-utils/) to convert console psf fonts into a simple ascii representation that is then easy to manipulate. You could use the following sequence to invert each glyph in a chosen font to create a new font:

```
psf2psftx myfont.psf myfont.psftx
./invert <myfont.psftx >inverted.psftx
psftx2psf inverted.psftx myfontinverted.psf
```

where the invert is a small awk script:

```
awk '
/ENDGLYPH/   { print glyph; glyph = "" }
/^\t[\.X]*$/ { glyph = $0 "\n" glyph; next }
             { print } '
```

For example, I used his screenshot emulation (which needs reportlab and PIL packages) to produce this image [image] after inverting the standard Linux console font `lat1-08.psfu`

```
zcat /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/lat1-08.psfu.gz >myfont.psf
...
echo abc >text
psftx-screenshot inverted.psftx text inverted.png
```

You may have some problems with the code depending on your version of python3, and I presume you still need to work on the font if you want both right-way up and upside-down versions of the characters in the same font, so do not embark on this lightly.

Comment: I'm king of cold with this solution , as there will be *LOT* of changes between fonts that way , it's not chunks of upside glyphs then another portions inverted. This answer is good, but it does not apply too well in my case. As you said in the end, it's just not worth it, but maybe can it be good on an optional mode